# Begin<Method> and End<Method> are missing in web service client stub

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, visual-studio-2010

I am porting a web service client application that was written with Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010. When I add the wsdl URL to VS2008 (using the .NET 2.0 compatibility dialog), a web service stub is generated that does not contain the `Begin<MethodName>` and `End<MethodName>` methods that are described in the [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz4bkcx2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Instead, a `<MethodName>Async` method and an associated event is generated.

I would prefer if I would not need to change the Begin/End calls in the code to the Async+event coding style.

How do I generate the Begin/End methods that are mentioned in [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz4bkcx2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: obviously the code that I was porting, is from pre-Visual-Studio-2005. Starting from Visual Studio 2005, Begin* and End* no longer are generated. The MSDN document lacks to point that out.

Answer (score 0):

did you add the Service using the "Add Service Reference" Dialog? There is a "Advanced" configuration button that opens up another dialog where you can say "Generate asynchronous operations", then Begin/End Methods get generated. The same dialog appears when you right click on an existing service reference and choose "Configure service reference".

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this site. It allows you to add the Begin and End methods.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/2110/begin-and-end-async-method-web-service-proxy-not-generated.aspx

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Consider posting relevant information in your answer.